# multiple style functions

Tags: openlayers, style

In my code I'm putting on an ol.interaction.Select interaction. I need to set the style and this is easy.

```
   new ol.interaction.Select({
            filter : function(feature, layer) {
                return me.inFilterSelect(feature, layer);
            },
            wrapX : false,
            style : stylePoligon
        });
```

I now have the need to set two styles, but one must be a function style (the styles depends on some attributes attached on the feature), and the other could be a function too or a simple new ol.style.style({...}).

How can I set such a thing, multiple styles of different types (one function and one ol.style.style) or multiple functions style? I'm using openlayer 4.0.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166506/openlayers-3-select-interaction-style-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenLayers supports [multiple styles](http://openlayersbook.github.io/ch06-styling-vector-layers/example-06.html). If you want to use more than one style, use an array with your styles or functions returning styles. Did you tried that? Why it is not working?

```
new ol.interaction.Select({
            filter : function(feature, layer) {
                return me.inFilterSelect(feature, layer);
            },
            wrapX : false,
            style : [stylePolygon, functionReturningStyle]
        });
```

Please show your attempt with an array to let us know where the problem is.

Comment: this helped me, i was wrong because my stylePolygon returned sometimes an array of styles and sometimes an ol.style.Style. i rearranged some thing and all worked

Answer (score 0):

Your function `stylePoligon` can return multiple styles. Each style returned has tyle `ol.style.Style`.

Example using feature's attribute `dominio` to select the style for the feature:

```
    function stylePoligon(feature, resolution) {
        var res;
        // console.log(feature);
        var dominio = feature.get('dominio');
        switch (dominio) {
            case 'PLANTA ORDENAMENTO':
                res = new ol.style.Style({
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: 'rgba(255, 206, 161, 0.2)'
                    }),
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: '#ffcea1',
                        width: 2
                    })
                });
                break;
            case 'PLANTA CONDICIONANTES':
                res = new ol.style.Style({
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: 'rgba(126, 224, 154, 0.2)'
                    }),
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: '#7ee09a',
                        width: 2
                    })
                });
                break;
            case 'infraestruturas':
                res = new ol.style.Style({
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: 'rgba(152, 88, 0, 0.2)'
                    }),
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: '#985800',
                        width: 2
                    })
                });
                break;
            case 'LOTEAMENTO':
                res = new ol.style.Style({
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: 'rgba(255, 171, 185, 0.2)'
                    }),
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: '#ffabb9',
                        width: 2
                    })
                });
                break;
            default:
                res = defaultStyle;
                break;
        }
        return [res];
    }
```

I use `defaultStyle` as:

```
    var defaultStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: [0, 0, 128, 0.8],
            width: 2
        })
    });
```

Comment: you return only one style (differente but the cardinality is one). i tried to return [result1,result2] but it doesn't work. how can i return that result